# Converting html menu to wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

I am trying to convert html to wordpress. The conversion is complete but I want to change the static html menu to a wordpress `wp_nav_menu`.

This is my static html code:

```
<li class="dropdown active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
    <!-- submenu-wrapper -->
    <div class="submenu-wrapper">
        <div class="submenu-inner">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="index2.html">Home2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu-wrapper -->
</li>
<!-- /Home -->

<!-- Pages -->
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Pages <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
    <!-- submenu-wrapper -->
    <div class="submenu-wrapper">
        <div class="submenu-inner">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="service.html">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="our-people.html">Our people</a></li>
                <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu-wrapper -->
</li>
<!-- /Pages -->

<!-- Services -->
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Services <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
    <!-- submenu-wrapper -->
    <div class="submenu-wrapper">
        <div class="submenu-inner">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="air.html">Air transportation</a></li>
                <li><a href="marine.html">Marine transportation</a></li>
                <li><a href="moving.html">Moving & storage</a></li>
                <li><a href="shipping.html">Shipping & operations</a></li>
                <li><a href="transportation.html">Transportation logistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="trucking.html">Trucking</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu-wra
```

Comment: Wordpress generates it own code for the menu. You need to build the menu in the Appearances > Menu area of Settings.

Comment: i got the menu, but how can i dropdown to menu in wordpress??

Comment: Use the standard WP functions for adding menus. If you don't know what you are doing, then do some tutorials.

Comment: okey i got it. i appreciate you for your valuable suggestion